# List comprehension in pure BASH?

Tags: bash, list-comprehension

Is it possible to do LC like in python and other languages but only using BASH constructs?

What I would like to be able to do, as an example is this:

```
function ignoreSpecialFiles()
{
    for options in "-L" "-e" "-b" "-c" "-p" "-S" "! -r" "! -w"; do
        if [[ $options "$1" -o $options "$2" ]];then
            return $IGNORED
        fi
    done
}
```

instead of using code like this:

```
if [[ -L "$1" -o -e "$1" -o -b "$1" -o -c "$1" -o -p "$1" -o -S "$1" -o\
! -r "$1" -o ! -w "$1" ]]
```

Do you know of any recipes for simulating LC like this??

## Edit:

A more LC specific example:

```
M = [x for x in S if x % 2 == 0] #is python
```

what is the most pythonic way to do the same in bash?

```
for x in S; do if x % 2 == 0;then (HERE MY HEAD EXPLODES) fi done
```

Comment: No.  What are you trying to do?  Use the right tool for the right job.  "If all you have is a hammer, every problem looks like a nail..."

Comment: it's the third time today that I read you quote associated with bash scripting @Adam ^^

Comment: "the most pythonic way to do the same in bash"? This is nonsense. The Pythonic way is to use Python. The Bash way is to use Bash.

Comment: @johnsyweb its not a nonsense to me. its common to borrow paradigm from different langages.

Comment: @Johnsyweb What I wanted was something not ugly, explicit, simple, not too complicated, flat if possible, not too dense, and perhaps readable... @slowdog answer is a good example. I believe that the sense of this question was to try and learn better code, using ideas that may have been born elsewhere, and playing with them to "solve" common problems. I feel like this is a part of python philosophy(ironpython, jython, ctypes?, boost.python?..). It's a shame to keep everything you learn in a separated closet ;) furthermore in this sector where we use different languages to say the same thing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a semi-general format for doing the equivalent of LC in bash with arrays:

```
outarray=()
for x in "${inarray[@]}"; do
    if SOMECONDITION; then
        outarray+=(SOMEFUNCTIONOFx)
    fi
done
```

Here's your second example in this format:

```
s=({1..10})
echo "${s[@]}"
# Prints: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
m=()
for x in "${s[@]}"; do
    if (( x % 2 == 0 )); then
        m+=($x)
    fi
done
echo "${m[@]}"
# Prints: 2 4 6 8 10
```

Here's another example, with a less trivial "function" but without the conditional:

```
paths=("/path/to/file 1" "/path/somewhere/else" "/this/that/the other" "/here/there/everywhere")
filenames=()
for x in "${paths[@]}"; do
    filenames+=( "$(basename "$x")" )
done
printf "'%s' " "${filenames[@]}"
# Prints: 'file 1' 'else' 'the other' 'everywhere'
```

Answer (score 23):

A loop in a command substitution looks like a list comprehension if you squint. Your second example could be written as:

```
M=$(for x in $S; do if [ $(( x % 2 )) == 0 ]; then echo $x; fi done)
```

Comment: This is quite close to the Python syntax. Of course, what it does internally is somewhat different, but the result is about the same. +2 (I wish)

Comment: This didn't work for me until I swapped out `M=$()` for `readarray -t M < <()`.

Comment: ...depends on whether one actually wants the result to be a genuine shell array; in the answer as given here, it's just a scalar.

Comment: @slowdog Please add the version that @cmcdragonkai describes so 'a genuine shell array' is returned, as using `M=$()` returns 'just a scalar' as @charles-duffy commented.  Would be useful have both solutions in the answer and let the user decide which output they want.

Answer (score 2):

What you're describing doesn't look like list comprehensions...  You can do what it looks like you want (use a variable to represent the test that you want to perform) using single brackets instead of double brackets.  As an example:

```
function ignoreSpecialFiles()
{
    for options in "-L" "-e" "-b" "-c" "-p" "-S" "! -r" "! -w"; do
        if [ $options "$1" -o $options "$2" ]
        then
            return $IGNORED
        fi
    done
}
```

Comment: @Gilles: now it is working. I am actually using `if test "$options" "$1" ;then` but is the same as []. this is for my specific example, but I would like to see more ideas regarding LS in general, even if I'm afraid that NO, may be the final answer...